# VideoCapture crashing with opencv2.0

Tags: c++, opencv

This simple program is crashing at VideoCapture.
My configuration is OpenCV 2.0, MinGW, Windows7

```
int main()
{ 
    cout<<"reached here"<<endl;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open("Z:\\snapshot\\streaminput\\video1.avi");
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"capture failed"<<endl;
        // print error msg
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"capture successful"<<endl;
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("gray",1);
    do
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cout<<"got a frame"<<endl;
        imshow("gray", frame);
        cvWaitKey(300);

    }while(1);
    //cvDestroyAllWindows();

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}


CALLSTACK:
#0 002FB4B8 cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int) ()(C:\OpenCV2.0\bin\libhighgui200.dll:??)
#1 77CCE115 ntdll!RtlAllocateMemoryZone() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#2 00000000 0x0022fe78 in ??() (??:??)

PROGRAMOUTPUT(BEFORE CRASH POINT):
 capture name is:Z:\snapshot\streaminput\video1.avi
 Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 9.874
 Press any key to continue.
```

Any idea what is wrong in this program or in configuration??